# Magento undefined function error

Tags: magento-1.8, php, configurable-product

I got this error message in category page.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getUsedProducts() in /var/www/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php on line 92.

How to fix this error...?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to call `getUsedProducts` on a simple product.

Comment: But i have appro 3000 configure product.

Comment: try to log at that line specified in the error message, the product id that gives the error and debug why you are getting there.

Comment: Tell me the solution.Plz

Comment: @RItesh, he did. *You* need to debug. That's the solution.